# Can HTTP traffic be proxied on a device with two ethernet interfaces?

Tags: networking, iptables

I would like to perform a man in the middle attack between a device I own (victim) and an HTTP server.
I have two network interfaces on my desktop (attacker).
*Attacker* is running Ubuntu.
*Attacker* has two network interfaces.
For simplicity, let's call *attacker*'s interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`.
`eth0` is connected to a router which is connected to a modem (internet).
`eth1` is connected to a LAN port of a router which has victim connected to another LAN port.

My current network configuration looks like this:

```
---------------     -------------------     ----------------------------     --------------------     ----------------------
| (Victim)    |     | (SOHO Router B) |     |        (Attacker)        |     | (SOHO  Router A) |     |                    |
| DHCP IP:    | <-> | IP:             | <-> |]-eth1 IP:    eth2 IP:---[| <-> | IP:              | <-> | (Modem / Internet) |
| 192.168.2.x |     | 192.168.2.1     |     | 192.168.2.x  192.168.1.x |     | 192.168.1.1      |     |                    |
---------------     -------------------     ---------------------------      --------------------     ----------------------
```

I, as *attacker*, want to sniff and modify HTTP traffic from victim to the internet.
The first hurdle is getting *victim* to access the internet.
My understanding is that I need to forward traffic on *attacker* between interfaces.

There is no (reasonable) way to set the default gateway or do any real configuration of *SOHO Router B*
other than setting the subnet and DHCP ranges.
I am limited to the web interface which is relatively nerfed.

I want to say I can use routing rules on attacker to get *victim* connected to the internet on all ports and
forward port 80 traffic to a local server running on *attacker*.
My attempts have been fruitless. Either my understanding of this network config is wrong or I might need to go back to the iptables manpage.